How to match csv items?
Using:
/\v(^|,)\zs([^,"]*|("[^"]*"))\ze(,|$)

I can match for csv items, including:

simple csv like ,abc,, whose content is just abc
csv items with question mark ,"abc,abc",, whose content is abc,abc

However, there's another nasty case that is double quotation mark, e.g.

,"""abc""", is an item that the content is "abc"
or even more complex """abc,abc""" means "abc,abc"

Is there a way to identify them correctly?

What do you want to do with the item? In all likelihood, you're better off with a CSV-aware text processing tool, like Miller

I would do:
\v(^|,)\zs([^,"]*|("[^"]*")|(""".{-}"""))\ze(,|$)

I have added to your solution a third alternative: """.{-}""".
It match a string that starts with """ and ends with """ but in a non greedy way (because of the {-} quantifier) such that with: """foo""","""bar""" it will match """foo""" or """bar""" but not """foo""","""bar""" .
Or even better:
\v(^|,)\zs(([^,"]+)|("([^"]*"")*[^"]*"))\ze(,|$)


like a charm :) thx!

Thanks for the feedback :-)

Use "" as an alternative to [^"], i.e.,
/\v(^|,)\zs([^,"]*|"([^"]|"")*")\ze(,|$)

